# how to put setTimeout after 10 iterarions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a each loop like below

```
$('#goldBarList tr:not(:eq(0))').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {  
    $(this).remove();  
});
```

as i have 4000 rows and each row has a checkbox. I need to remove those rows having their checkbox checked.
However, the browser is giving stop running this script error?
because this loop is taking more time to finish.
so i just want to use `setTimeout` after 10 iterations and continue the loop after 0.5sec..
means i want the loop to sleep for 1/2sec after every 10 iterartions..
please give me some code reference...

Thanks...

Comment: Why do you need such a (too) huge table?

Comment: Add a counter variable and then increase it inside the loop

Comment: 4000 rows? you should probably look into pagination.

Comment: You don't need to wrap the `.remove`  in an `each` loop, that only makes it slow.

Comment: I don't think a delay will help at all - 4000 rows is a MASSIVE amount and far too much to display on the web. You should paginate that with a filter for searching. Look at http://datatables.net

Comment: without wrapping .remove what i acn do..?

Comment: I can not imagine someone walking a table of 4000 rows to check those checkboxes

Comment: As noted in my answer below, you don't need to have it wait any amount of time to avoid the "stop running script" error - you just have to split it into setTimeouts - even if they're 0. Also, when writing my jsFiddle, I noticed that most of the overhead is in checking the `:has(:checkbox:checked)`. You could save yourself some processing time if you added an attr to the tr that reflects the checked state of the checkbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems you're really looking for is to be able to remove those elements without the browser timing out. Splitting the calls up using window.setTimeout does the trick, even if the timeout is 0. The code below does this in batches of 500.

**EDIT:** Updated to improve performance. (Thanks Bergi.)

```
var removeTds = function($el) {
    var elements = $el.filter(":lt(500)"),
        count = elements.length;

    elements.remove();
    $el = $el.filter(":gt(499)");
    if (count === 500) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            removeTds($el);
        }, 0);
    }
};

removeTds($('tbody tr:not(:eq(0))').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)'));
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wzsjV/5/).

Comment: You're very welcome. Glad to help, and thanks for the upvote! I've had similar issues in the past and I know they can be a pain.

Comment: You should not do the selection each time.

Comment: @Bergi, I'm pretty sure you have to because you're removing the items each time. If you didn't re-select, wouldn't you be calling `.remove()` on the same elements over and over?

Comment: @Grinn: No, because you wouldn't select only 500 elements of course. You are selecting all matching elements and then slice the first 500 each time; better would be to select all elements only once and then loop over the existing selection.

Comment: @Bergi: Good point. Updated to instead take all the elements the first time, and slice them out in groups of 500 using the `:lt` and `:gt` pseudo-selectors. The performance seems better.

Comment: hi If i want to know the row numbers which were added to 'elements' what should i do..?

Answer (score 1):

Well after re-reading your question I realized I totally mis-understood you.

Here is my revised function allowing you to process only a small "chunk" of the array at once. However if DOM reflow is causing you a large headache try using a Document Fragment to build up the tree first.

Revised Answer:

```
function _each(arr, fn/*callback(elem,i)*/, limit/*items per pass*/) {
    limit = limit || 10;
    var count = 0,
        len = arr.length;

    function run() {
        var d = limit;
        while (d-- && len >= count) {
            fn(arr[count], count++);
        }
        if (len > count) setTimeout(run, 1000); // one second is just to show you it working.
    }
    run();
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/z9dzt/3/).

After answering this I saw some value in expanding the method a bit more to accept a complete callback.

http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/hAUcX/7/ ([less readable but smaller version](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/hAUcX/6/)) here is a demo with the revised function. I did notice quite a significant perceived performance difference when changing the timeout from 0 to 1ms.

Comment: Simplify to `while (d-- && len < count) fn(arr[count], count++);` and I'll give you an upvote :-)

Comment: @Bergi good call. I missed that when cleaning up the code :) However it would need to be `while (d-- && len >= count) fn(arr[count], count++);` to maintain the same functionality.

Answer (score 0):

use the parameter reference within the `.each` coupled with `return`:

```
$(...).each(function(i,e){
  if (i >= 10) return; // dtop after 10 iterations
  // original code
})
```

You can also use [`.slice()`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) to select only 10 items, then move on to the `.each`:

```
$(...).slice(0,10).each(function(){
  // original code
});
```

If you wanted to execution this in groups, `.slice()` will also make that easier as you can essentially sip `n` elements and grab `m` elements (then process that group).

Comment: when i tried to use break... it saying like  can not have break outside of loop... i don't want to break the loop.. i want to make the loop sleep for 1/2 sec after 10 iterartions..then continue... again after 10 iteration sleep...like wise i want...

Comment: @user:oops, still waking up. Use `return` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can break the loop after 10 iterations by using a counter then a break statement

```
var i = 0; 
$('#goldBarList tr:not(:eq(0))').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').each(function() {  
   if(i >= 10)
   {  
       break;
   }
   else
   {
       $(this).remove();
       i++;
   }

});
```

Comment: can not have break outside of loop... i don't want to break the loop.. i want to make the loop sleep for 1/2 sec after 10 iterartions..then continue... again after 10 iteration sleep...like wise i want...